# How can I change shell in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell, chsh

I have a Ubuntu Server VPS and I want to use `/bin/bash/` as my shell. How can I change my shell? I have root access but I don't work as root. So dash is my default shell now.

I have read [How do I make Bash my default shell on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/46748/how-do-i-make-bash-my-default-shell-on-ubuntu) and `chsh` seams to be the preferred way to go. But when I type `chsh /bin/bash` I get this message:
`chsh: unknown user /bin/bash`

And if I just type `/bin/bash` the Bash shell seams to work fine. How to change it?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

To change a shell, use the bare `chsh` command.  This will prompt you for the new shell.  You do not have to run anything as root.

Comment: Ah, that was even better!

Comment: don't forget to log out and log back in to see the change.

Comment: Doesn't work as normal user:

$ chsh
You may not change the shell for 'user'.

Comment: Works for me.  Sounds like your system has been deliberately locked down.

Comment: I use ssh, but chsh asks me for password which I don't know. Any way to work around this?

Comment: +1 @Henning I found `chsh -s /bin/bash web` to work, as in the [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/119182/21353) from Dentrasi. I can now use tab file/folder path autocomplete at the terminal with my new non-root user (as this is setup in the`.bashrc` file in the user's home directory, I believe (find it with `ls -al`)

Comment: @Henning seems to be related to external domain login at my institution.

Answer (score 148):

When running as root, you can use `chsh` to change other users shells. The syntax you want to use it this. You can change your own shell without root rights.

`chsh -s /bin/bash username`

Comment: -1 chsh does not need to be run as root to change your *own* shell. Changing others' shells requires root.

Comment: This worked. I always get the "You may not change the shell for ..." error message.

Comment: Logout and log back in after to observe the change

Comment: +1 I found this to work, after trying `chsh` command when logged in as the user and getting "You may not change the shell for ..."

Comment: @Broam - This absolutely **does** have to be run as root on some systems. See the above messages.

Answer (score 65):

You can change your default shell for your user by using the usermod command.

```
sudo usermod -s <shell> <username>
```

replace  with the name of the shell you want to use (i.e. /bin/bash) and  with the username for which you want to change it.

This will set the default shell for the username selected in the /etc/passwd file.

Comment: Use `usermod` if you see "chsh You may not change the shell for..."

Comment: voting up, since chsh didn't work for me indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Important to note that `usermod` requires `sudo`